# footnote rule on cover page

Tags: footnotes, titles, rules, article, covers

I have a document with a cover page and foonote. I would like to add a rule above the foonote. What is the way to do this?

```
\documentclass[english,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}

\title{ddd}


\author{ccc%
\thanks{bbb%
}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
aaa
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your document preamble, add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\footnoterule\relax}{}{}{}
```

This removes the line that clears the `\footnoterule` from `\maketitle`. If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), you have two options:

1. Either load `hyperref` *after* performing the patch and you're good-to-go; or
2. (if loading `hyperref` *before* this patch) patch `\HyOrg@maketitle` which contains the original pre-`hyperref` `\maketitle` information. Remember to brace the patch with a `\makeatletter`-`\makeatother` pair, since you're working with macros containing `@`. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)

---

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd` has the following interface:

```
\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

where it searches for `<search>` in `<cmd>` and replaces it with `<replace>`. If the replacement is successful, it executes `<success>`, otherwise `<failure>`. Therefore, the above patch searches for `\let\footnoterule\relax` and removes it (replaces it with an empty group `{}`. Since it works in the default `article` document class, no `<success>` or `<failure>` executions are necessary, although you could add them yourself.

Comment: awesome, thanks. could you just explain what was going on? i couldn't figure it out

Comment: For some reason this stopped working. When I do the tracing in `etoolbox` i get: `[debug] -- search pattern not found in replacement text`

Comment: the issue is i started using the `hyperref` package which seems to conflict with this...

Comment: @Alex: I've added your options when loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) also. Since `\maketitle` may contain footnotes, `hyperref` intervenes, causing the "search pattern not found" with [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd`. Easiest is to load `hyperref` *after* `\patchcmd`.

Comment: much appreciated.